# What limits Google Maps from displaying when zooming in tighter than 1:1,411 in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

In QGIS 2.18.15 while using Google Maps as a basemap anytime I zoom in tighter than 1:1,411 Google Maps stops displaying.

What is limiting Google Maps from displaying when attempting to zoom in tighter?

I've been searching for an answer, but I don't seem to find anything.  I've installed QGIS as 32bit and I don't have (never did) the "Tile Map Scale Plugin" installed.

Comment: are you using openlayer plugin?

Comment: Yes, I'm using openlayer plugin to add the basemap

Comment: Go to `https://github.com/sourcepole/qgis-openlayers-plugin/tree/5647d01d95bb70c6b8838e8aae61200afc4f445d/openlayers/weblayers/html` and open the google _xxx.html and search `maxResolution` or `numZoomLevels` for find the limits

Comment: Try the [QuickMapServices](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/) plugin. There is native TMS provider support in QGIS 2.18. This is super fast and supports overzoom.

Comment: I agree, use the QMS plugin for 2.x. If not, use the Tiles Server (XYZ) from the Browser panel. For example to add Google Hybrid, right click Tiles Server (XYZ) and add https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x={x}&y={y}&z={z} - bonus is you can rotate the imagery in the print composer